# Why is my VBA SearchFormat working backwards?

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, this one has me flabbergasted. I set the FindFormat for Bold, and the SearchFormat to False, so the first non-bold instance of the search string would be selected. But when I leave the Found.Select line in Debug, it’s the bold instance that’s selected! Am I missing something? PS i was previously declared...

```
Range(Cells(3, 3).Address(), Cells(lRow, 3).Address()).Select

Dim cn(0 To 300) As String
Dim Found As Range
Application.FindFormat.Font.Bold = True
i = 0

With Selection

    For Each Drawing In dn
            Set Found = .Find(Drawing, SearchFormat:=False)
            Found.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
            cn(i) = ActiveCell.Value
            i = i + 1
    Next

End With
```

Comment: Setting SearchFormat to False just means it will ignore formatting. It will just find the first instance.

Comment: If you want to find non-bold items why not set the format to that!?

Comment: Didn't know you could. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Is your problem actually solved?

Answer (score 0):

*The correct first element to look after is not passed. And VBA is taking the default one, which is the first, but it starts looking after it.*

This is some example data, searching for number in columns B:

[image]

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim myR     As Range
    Dim myS     As Range
    Set myS = Range("B1:B5") 'change the range to "C1:C5" correspondingly 
    With myS
        Set myR = .Find(1)
        Debug.Print myR.Row
        Set myR = .Find(1, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count))
        Debug.Print myR.Row
    End With
End Sub
```

[This is the "After" parameter in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ff839746(v=office.14).aspx):

> The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn’t searched until the method wraps back around to this cell. If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.

Thus you give the last cell possible as a start. It knows that it should start After it. So, it theoretically has nothing better to do and simply starts from the beginning of the range. The idea of the After parameter is to set the last value that would be checked. Thus, if we have only one value it is always returned correctly, no matter of the After  parameter. With more than one value, it returns the first value it finds.

Thus, in the code above, because of the usage of After the `Range.Find()` searches the cells in the following sequence:

**B1 > B2 > B3 > B4 > B5**

Without the After the sequence is the following:

**B2 > B3 > B4 > B5 > B1**

It is worthy to run the code with the examples a couple of times. Indeed, the default parameter is not set the way one would expect. I mean, if I give a range and I look into it, I expect to check the first cell first by default. And not to check the first cell last, because it is the default parameter of After, when it is not set.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. I knew about After, but I was assuming that the find format would skip the Bold cell and wrap around back to the beginning. Didn't realize SearchFormat worked that way. I suppose I could put Found.Select in an If block and test for Bold...